# Draw half arrow

Tags: drawing, graphics

I would like to draw in Mathematica two **half arrows** next to each other. Something like this:
[image]

Here is my attempt:

```
x0 = -0.2;
y0 = -0.2;
k = -1;
dist = 0.02;(*distance between two arrows*)
c1 = Max[c /. Solve[y0 == k x0 + c, c]];
c2 = Max[c /. Solve[-y0 == k (-x0) + c, c]];
xA = x0 - dist/Sqrt[1 + k^2];
yA = k xA + c1;
xB = -x0 - dist/Sqrt[1 + k^2];
yB = k xB + c2;

Graphics[
{{Thick, Arrowheads[0.05], Arrow[{{x0, y0}, -{x0, y0}}],
Arrow[{{xB, yB}, {xA, yA}}]},
{White, Polygon[{{x0, y0}, -{x0, y0}, {xB, yB}, {xA, yA}}]}},
PlotRange -> {{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}}, Frame -> True, 
PlotRangeClipping -> True]
```

Form the code you can see that I've drawn two `Arrow`s, while covering the right part of each of arrows by white `Polygon`.
Here is my result:

[image]

(The arrows are under 45° degree angle which was done on purpose.)

I was wondering if there is some `Graphics` function in Mathematica for **half arrow**. Or if one can somehow modify the `Arrow` `Graphics` in order to get half arrow.
I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can also design a new arrow style by use `Graphics`

```
arrowStyle = 
  Graphics[{Black, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {-1, .2}, {-.8, 0}, {0, 0}}]}];
semiArrow = Arrowheads[{{0.2, 1, arrowStyle}}];
Graphics[{semiArrow, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
  Arrow[{{1 + .1, 1 - .1}, {.1, -.1}}]}]
```

[image]

It is the first attempt. Late we  can adjust the thickness of line and the position of arrow to  get another style.

**Update**
For 3D, we still need to draw an invisiable half arrow.

```
arrowStyle = 
  Graphics[{Black, FaceForm[Red], 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {-1, .2}, {-.8, 0}, {0, 0}}], EdgeForm[], 
    FaceForm[], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {-1, -.2}, {-.8, 0}, {0, 0}}]}];
semiArrow = Arrowheads[{{0.2, 1, arrowStyle}}];
Graphics3D[{semiArrow, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This looks like the unicode character "rightwards harpoon over leftwards harpoon", with code U+21cc. It can be found [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromDigits.html). We might use it in Mathematica like this:

```
harpoon = FromCharacterCode@FromDigits["21cc", 16];

Graphics[{
  Text[Style[harpoon, FontSize -> 25], {0, 0}],
  Text[Style[harpoon, FontSize -> 25], {10, 5}],
  Rotate[
   Text[Style[harpoon, FontSize -> 25], {5, 5}],
   30 Degree
   ]
  }]
```

[image: Output]

Other fonts might look more similar to your example.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**   Since I don't know your ultimate goal, here is my attempts.

```
    imSize = 100;
    poly = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 2}, {9, 2}, {9, 4}, {14, 0}}];
 arrows = Rotate[Column[{Graphics[poly, ImageSize -> imSize], 
        Rotate[Graphics[poly, ImageSize -> imSize], 180 Degree]}, 
       Spacings -> 0], 45 Degree];
    Overlay[{Graphics[{FaceForm[], Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}, 
       Frame -> True], arrows}, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

---

```
 poly = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 2}, {9, 2}, {9, 4}, {14, 0}}];
 Rotate[Column[{Graphics[poly], Rotate[Graphics[poly], 180 Degree]}], 45 Degree]
```

[image]